# Optimizing Black-box function in Pyomo

Tags: optimization, pyomo

Is it possible to optimize a problem in pyomo in which the objective function and/or constraints are written in other language like C or C++?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you would want to use the [`ExternalFunction` expression object](http://pyomo.readthedocs.io/en/latest/library_reference/expressions/classes.html?highlight=externalfunction#pyomo.core.expr.current.ExternalFunctionExpression).

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I tried using this but encountered an error. The question regarding that error is posted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55176181/optimizing-fortran-function-in-pyomo). If you can share a reproducible example or guide me to a code (maybe on github) where ExternalFunction expression object is used, it would be immensely helpful.